# Must spacetime be homogeneous?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, symmetry

According to Einstein's equations of general relativity, space must be homogeneous. It can't have an edge or a centre. Is the same true of 4-dimensional spacetime – must it also be homogeneous?

Comment: "According to Einstein's equations of general relativity, space must be homogeneous" Do you have any source for this claim (just asking because I am not familiar with Einstein's field equations)? Or do you perhaps refer to the [FLRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric)? If so, homogeneity it is an assumption (I think).

Comment: The sentence you wrote is not true, the equation's do not demand that space must be homogeneous. For example, one of the solutions to Einstein's equation is the Schwarzschild metric, which describes the region around a black hole. This is not homogeneous. @Jonas is right, you probably confuse this with the FLRW metric, which is also a solution for Einstein's equations, but to find this solution, homogeneity is an initial assumption.

Answer (score 3):

It's often various cosmological models that model space as being homogeneous.

It's also only approximately true on a very large scale.  On a scale even as large as galaxies space is not homogeneous.

Einstein's equations don't require it, it's just some cosmological models that use Einstein's equations that do.

See also [Cosmological Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle)

So space can be modelled as homogeneous, even in a Big-Bang type of cosmological model, or Concordance Cosmology.

Space-time would not be homogeneous even with those models, if you mean would space-time look the same at all times as well as places, as they contain the Big Bang, and the matter near that event would be more densely packed than later on.